# Value from array is not printing in html

Tags: angular

I need to display a response from api using interpolation.

I have tried:-

```
response['data'][0].value// can console this value here


this.variable = response;


<p>{{  variable['data'][0].value }}</p>
```

response will be :-

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "value": "abc",
    },
    {
        "value": "efg",

    },
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you write what is `response`

Comment: @OrhanÖzkerçin  yeah I have updated the question! Thanks!

Comment: the value is displaying now but am getting some error regarding this in console as "Cannot read properties of undefined". Some of the html elements  where this value is binding are displaying blank because of this!

Comment: I am actually binding this value to form input value using ngModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing this.

```js
const response = {
  "data": [{
      "value": "abc",
    },
    {
      "value": "efg",

    },
  ]
}

const value = response.data[0].value;
const value_2 = response['data'][0]['value'];
console.log(value);
console.log(value_2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!